# How can I access UITableView's index path in my segue prepare function?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to access the stringSchoolID variable from the tableView function in the prepare function. It's a dynamic variable which changes as a different row item in the TableView is clicked. The arrays are populated by Firebase so I removed that part of the code - you can assume they are populated as I've already tested this.

As a solution I tried declaring the variable outside of the functions but this didn't work, the destination segue just receives an empty string (as it was declared). All help is appreciated!

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewSearch: UITableView!

    struct School {
        let schoolID: String
        let schoolName: String
        let schoolTown: String
        let schoolCountry: String
    }

    var schoolArray: [School] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }    
}

extension SearchViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "SearchSelectionSegue", sender: self)
        var stringSchoolID: String = self.schoolArray[indexPath.row].schoolID
        print(stringSchoolID)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let searchSelectionSegue = segue.destination as! SchoolProfileViewController
        searchSelectionSegue.stringSegue = 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
let stringSchoolID = self.schoolArray[indexPath.row].schoolID    
performSegue(withIdentifier: "SearchSelectionSegue", sender: stringSchoolID)
```

And in:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let searchSelectionSegue = segue.destination as! SchoolProfileViewController
    searchSelectionSegue.stringSegue = sender as? String
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row` to get the index of cell selected.

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let searchSelectionSegue = segue.destination as! SchoolProfileViewController
        guard let index: Int = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row else { return }
        searchSelectionSegue.stringSegue = schoolArray[index].schoolID
    }
```